# discord.py, ошибка при команде =unmute

Tags: discord, discord.py

Моя проблема в том, что когда я запускаю бота, то при команде unmute он размучивает самого себя. То есть я его запускаю, пишу =unmute @user, на что он мне отвечает: Moderator | Tm#3109 успешно размучен. Если что, Moderator | Tm#3109 это мой бот.
Вот код:

```
@bot.command()
async def unmute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=920759706417504256)
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user} **успешно размучен**")

Ниже находится скриншот моих сообщений и сообщений бота.
```

[image]

Comment: Я разобрался уже

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя сократить и убрать всё ненужное?

```
@bot.command()
async def unmute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=920759706417504256)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user} **успешно размучен**")
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/768591)